# Unable to load Swagger-UI with spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, springfox

I am trying to dynamically document my SpringBoot application's REST API using Swagger.

In order to do that I am using springfox and it's swagger integration. I have followed the official documentation, which can be [found here](http://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/#springfox-swagger-ui).

Once I finished implementing the integration I can access the JSON output via http://localhost:8080/v2/api-docs, however I am unable to see any information in the Swagger UI via http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html.

This is my setup:

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <main.basedir>${basedir}/../..</main.basedir>
        <ing.continuous-delivery.version>00.04.04</ing.continuous-delivery.version>
        <maven.assembly.version>2.3</maven.assembly.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- tag::spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- end::spring -->

        <!-- tag::web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- end::web -->

        <!--  tag::swagger -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--  end:: swagger -->
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Web MVC configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }

}
```

Security configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**", "/swagger-resources").permitAll();
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable();
        httpSecurity.headers().frameOptions().disable();
    }
}
```

Swagger configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).select().apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any()).build();
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you see Swagger UI but it does not load your api-doc?

Comment: Can you post the output of running curl http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html or Fiddler (if on Windows)?

Comment: API-DOC works just fine

Comment: The issue was with an interceptor that I implemented which verified for a certain header

Answer (score 2):

I'm bad for English, that's why GoogleTranslate.

Nowadays spingdoc is available, which implements openapi3, it gives you the same expected functionality and it is much easier to use it, already in an [answer to another question](http://localhost:8080/v3/api-docs/) I explained how to do it, in addition to how to customize the information of the api using java annotations

SpringDoc simplifies the generation and maintenance of API documents, based on the OpenAPI 3 specification, for Spring Boot 1.x and 2.x applications.

For magic to happen we simply add the dependency to our pom:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.32</version>
    </dependency>
```

then access the description that already has it http://localhost:8080/v3/api-docs/

and for swagger: http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html

that's all there is to it.

Answer (score -1):

While trying to access the swagger UI, you need to add your API's base url before `/swagger-ui.html`.

Something like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/nameOfAPI/swagger-ui.html
```

This article helped me: 
https://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api